# Randon Error Processing on Pentaho CDE dashboard for MDX query widget

Tags: java, pentaho, olap-cube, mondrian

I am facing error processing on some widgets while loading dashboards on my applictaion randomly.

```
In the catalina.log, for one or two widgets, it is showing :
    mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Internal error: Query required more than 12 iterations
```

and for one or two widgets, it is showing :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But if I select the same dashboard again, it'll run perfectly. It is behaving very flakily.

To fix the iteration error, I did :

```
 mondrian.rolap.evaluate.MaxEvalDepth to 50 in mondrian.properties , which is 10 by default
```

This got me rid of iteration errors, but resulted in a `java.lang.NullPointerException` for other two widgets permanently except for default loading of dashboard. Due to which, I considered that the mondrian cache is getting overflowed or corrupted.

To fix this, I set `maxElementsInMemory` to 20000 for `mondrian-catalog-cache` in ehcache.xml, which is 30 by default
which solved the continous occurrennce of **`java.lang.NullPointerException`**, 
but situation again is same , i.e. dashboards are behaving flaky as earilier.

As i have seen on forums many people have faced similar problems.

Comment: (doesn't look like an mdx question - maybe that tag is a little misleading - I think a java tag might be better)

Comment: Two remarks: 1) I believe this same question was asked (and answered) in the Pentaho user group. Multiplying your questions in multiple forums doesn't increase the probability of getting an answer. 2) Adding comments begging for help doesn't do you any good.

Comment: @nsousa two good points - if the application is throwing an error then this question needs to be directed at the user group / contributors to the code base / company behind the application. At best we can provide a workaround for non-open source, or a suggestion for possible improvement to open source. I'm deleting the mdx tag as this question has no mdx content.

Comment: @nsousa:we got your input and working on that input as you provided in group.