# MDX Query behaving abrupt with degenerate dimension on CDE dashboard

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap, mondrian, degenerate-dimension

Following is my query:

```
WITH
    SET [sp] AS
        ([time.fin].[day].[${parDate}]:[time.fin].[day].[${partoDate}])

SET [factory] AS
    {[organization].[org].[Fact1],[organization].[org].[Fact2],[organization].[org].[Fact3]}

MEMBER [btype].[b] AS
     AGGREGATE(IIF('${param}'='All',
                    [btype].[type].members,
                     [btype].[type].[${param}]
        ))    

SELECT
NON EMPTY {[factory]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {[sp]}ON ROWS
FROM [cube1]
WHERE ([btype].[b], [Measures].[qty])
```

in this , **btype is the degenerate dimension**.
When i execute this query on CDE .. sometimes I get **java.lang.nullpointerexception** , the behaviour is very random. Often, it gives the result and for default load , it always results positive . But for date range change , I randomly get the exception.

my fact_table structure has 5 normal dimension and 3 degenerates .

meanwhile, I have also observed that if add some more grain to the query , then the exception doesn't appear anymore. But adding that doesn't fullfill my required result.

Is it something to do with degenerate dimension concept or high cardinality issue

Comment: this is relatively straightforward `mdx` so unsure that your problem is the `mdx`

Comment: duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755017/randon-error-processing-on-pentaho-cde-dashboard-for-mdx-query-widget

Comment: i think the actual problem lies somewhere in degenerate dimension concept and not in mdx.  I started this new thread , because this was a more specified and defined problem , rather than generic like that one..  the mdx query that i mentioned is for reference only

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this measure needs to be more explicit:

```
MEMBER [btype].[b] AS
     AGGREGATE(IIF('${param}'='All',
                    [btype].[type].members,
                     [btype].[type].[${param}]
        ))
```

If you change it to the following do you encounter the error?

```
MEMBER [btype].[b] AS 
    Sum
    (
      IIF
      (
        '${param}' = 'All'
       ,[btype].[type].MEMBERS
       ,[btype].[type].[${param}]
      )
    ,[Measures].[qty]
    )
```

Comment: my first approach was to calculate it explicitly only .. which din't work out .. then I tried it to do explicitly using aggregate .. which has reduced the frequency of exception occuring . . but still not able to get rid of this

Comment: ....and using `Sum` rather than `Aggregate` - they are not the same: and Aggregate can sometimes behave quite surprisingly. Please try swapping to `Sum` to test if `Aggregate` is your problem.

Comment: I considered Sum as recursively adding the   [Measures].[qty] for each member of [btype].. which might increase the iterations and degrade the performance . and throwing the exception randomly,, So I replaced it with Aggreagate which applies the default aggregation for the measure on specified members impliciltly..   and along with that I also declared degenerate dimension ([btype]) members as unique members in the cube definition.. these two changes has remarkably reduced the frequency of exception .. and also I have verified the results